# For loop to close/exit application

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop, multidimensional-array, exit

This code is supposed to close the application when all tiles on a board are == to null, but currently when the loop runs it exits the application as soon as it finds just 1 tile that is null. How do I fix that?

Thanks!

```
public void close(){
        for (int row = 0; row < 4; row++){
            for (int col = 0; col < 4; col++){
                if (tiles[row][col] == null) {
                    System.exit(0);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because your logic is wrong. It should be like the following instead.

```
public void close(){
    for (int row = 0; row < 4; row++){
        for (int col = 0; col < 4; col++){
            if (tiles[row][col] != null) {
                return; // leave this function and don't exit for any non-null tile
            }
        }
    }
    System.exit(0);
}
```